# How to attach input file to product custom option in magento?

Tags: php, jquery, html, magento

I need to take input file and want to attach that file while adding product to cart programmatically.
i want to attach file like photo to sale order while adding to cart

How would i achieve that?
below is what i do for normal text field. similarly i want for input type file.

```
$request = new Varien_Object(array(
'qty'=>1,
'options' => array(3=>'test') // 3 is id of custom option
));

    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($my_product, $request);

    $cart->addProduct($sub_product,$request);
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Help me Out

Answer (score -1):

Magento includes a file type custom option type that can be assigned to products.

1. Create or edit an existing product
2. Click the **Custom Options** tab on the left
3. Click the Add New Option button
4. Select **File** for the **Input Type**

[image: File custom options type]

When set correctly, a field will become available on the Product View page for the customer to upload a file.

Comment: yes thank you i know this... what i want to do is i have form. customer will select file and i want to attach file to the product file custom option while adding to cart programatically .